# Generating function for counting compositions of $n$ with parts from a given set

Tags: combinatorics

I was given the next question:

$A_n$ is marked to be the **number** of all of the sequences from a subset of the 
naturals to $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ such that their sum is $n$ (a natural number) ** **which means that the order matters**

For example: for $A_5$ **some part** of the sequences are <1,1,1,1,1> , <1,2,2> , <2,2,1>

I was asked to find the generating function that suits this problem, and what I mean by this is finding the function $f$ such that $f$= $A_0$ + $A_1x$ + $A_2x^2$+...

I'd really like some help with this question, Thank you very much!

p.s.:
$A_0=0$

Comment: Did you try to find the possible recursive relation of $A_n$'s?

Comment: @SachpazisStelios Sadly I cannot use recursive methods because we did not study those yet =(

Comment: I was asked to prove it using generating functions..how will induction be helpful in this case? @charMD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We observe: $$\frac{x}{1-x}=x^1+x^2+x^3+\ldots$$ 
>   carries as exponents the possible solutions $1,2,3,\ldots$ of one $x_i$ in
>   $$x_1+x_2+x_3+\ldots+x_k=n\qquad k\geq 1, n\geq k$$
>   Therefore  the number of *compositions* of $n$ with $k$ variables $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ of
>   $$\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^k$$

Since we want to restrict the solutions to be elements from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ we take
\begin{align*}
\frac{x-x^7}{1-x}=x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6
\end{align*}

> Since the number of variables is at least $1$ up to $n$ for $A_n$ we obtain as generating function
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_nx^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{x-x^7}{1-x}\right)^n\\
> &=\frac{x-x^7}{1-x}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{x-x^7}{1-x}}\\
> &=x+2x^2+4x^3+8x^4+\color{blue}{16}x^5+32x^6+63x^7+\cdots
> \end{align*}
>
> whereby the last line was obtained with some help of Wolfram Alpha.

$$ $$

> *Example:* We find e.g. $A_5=16$ which represents the $\color{blue}{16}$ compositions of $5$
>   \begin{align*}
> &<1,1,1,1,1,1>,\\
> &<1,1,1,2>,<1,1,2,1>,<1,2,1,1>,<2,1,1,1>,\\
> &<1,1,3>,<1,3,1>,<3,1,1>\\
> &<1,2,2>,<2,1,2>,<2,2,1>\\
> &<1,4>,<4,1>\\
> &<2,3>,<3,2>\\
> &<5>
> \end{align*}

Comment: @Lola: You're welcome! :-)

Comment: @Lola: Thanks a lot for granting the bounty! :-)

Comment: No problem :) Sorry for the bother Markus Scheuer, but could you help me with my recent question in generating functions? The answer that was given there was a false one =(

Comment: @Lola: I've added an answer. Regards,